# Android AVD set custom hardware

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am trying to decrease the ridiculous CPU usage of my Android emulator.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706018/1154610) I found out that the CPU usage can be greatly decreased by disabling audio.

### Solutions

I found out there are three ways to run the emulator without audio.

1. As a command line flag:

   ```
   $ emulator -avd <name> -noaudio
   ```
2. By editing `~/.android/<name>.avd/config.ini` and replacing this line:

   ```
   hw.audioInput=yes
   ```

   with these two:

   ```
   hw.audioInput=no
   hw.audioOutput=no
   ```
3. Instead of using the graphical AVD manager, use the following command to create an emulator:

   ```
   $ android create avd -n <name> -t <target>
   ```

### Cons

All of these methods have downsides though.

1. Requires to pass the `-noaudio` flag each time. This means it can't be run from AVD manager.
2. `config.ini` is reset each time an edit is made using AVD manager.
3. Requires to explicitly set every property of the device instead of just being able to use a preset configuration.

### Attempted (failed) solution

I decided it might help to just clone an existing device and disable the audio there.

However¸ this just created `~/.android/devices.xml` and I couldn't fine any reference how to disable audio by default nor any `ini` files containing hardware definitions.

### Question

Is it possible to create a predefined hardware configuration that has sound disabled by default? If so, how?

Comment: "this just created ~/.android/avd/devices.xml" -- I don't have that file, but I do have `~/.android/devices.xml`. "I couldn't fine any reference how to disable audio by default" -- well, none of this is documented much, if at all. That being said, in `devices.xml`, I see various devices that I cloned from existing devices, and I see a `<d:mic>true</d:mic>` element that could be flipped to `false`. I do not see any elements related to audio output, though. I also have not tried changing `<d:mic>` to see what effects it may have.

Comment: My mistake, it is in `~/.android/devices.xml` indeed. I believe disabling the audio output is even more important than the input.

Comment: If you're using Android Studio, this is a good solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64696876/1942551