# Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

Tags: android-studio

[ while opening AVD Manager getting

Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'  got this error ? How to remove error ? ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhBKy.jpg)

Answer (score 13):

1. Go to: Tools > Android > AVD Manager
2. Press the "edit" (pencil) icon next to your AVD
3. Change "Graphics" to "Software".

Comment: I'm having this issue in Visual Studio / Windows. Any way to access AVD manager?

Comment: It's not working with me. First, Android Studio 3.2.1 Tools doesn't have "Android" in the dropdown. It DOES have "AVD Manager". But when I edit, I can't change "Graphics" to "Software". Option is set to "Automatic" and is GREYED OUT.

Comment: @DSlomer64 The reason it's grayed out is because the virtual device has playstore enabled on it. Try creating another virtual device with out playstore support and you will be able to select a value.

Comment: @HiteshBisht `creating another virtual device with out playstore support` and how does one do that?

Comment: @likejudo That is very simple. When you click on "Create virtual devices" a window opens where you can select from some device from list. In that table of list there is a column called "Play Store" that denotes if playstore is there or not in the device. You can also see playstore icon in the row for "Pixel 2" and "Pixel" device. So you just have to either select another device or create one yourself and it will not have playstore installed in it.

Comment: It's so weird that it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem pluggin in a microphone and then removing it. Never had that problem again.

Comment: This seemed to work, but only while Windows 10 thought it had a microphone plugged in. After unplugging, the bad behaviour returned.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Sdk -> emulator -> lib` and then open configuration settings named **hardware properties**, find the `hw.AudioInput` field and set default to `no`:

[image: click this link to see the screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

One option, following @palehorse's terse clue, is to edit your AVD's config.ini to disable audio.

1. Android Studio > Tools > AVD manager ...
2. Against your (previously setup) Virtual Device > Actions > Down arrow [Click it] > Show on Disk ...
3. This will take you to a directory like `C:\Users\<username>\.android\avd\my_API_29_-_Android_10.avd`
4. In that directory edit `config.ini`
5. Replace ...

   ```
   hw.audioInput=yes
   ```

   ... with ...

   ```
   hw.audioInput=no
   hw.audioOutput=no
   ```

   An entry for `hw.audioOutput` did not previously exist.
6. Restart the emulator a few times to get rid of lingering error messages.

See [Android AVD set custom hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893571/android-avd-set-custom-hardware) for other ways to disable audio.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem:

1. pluggin in a microphone
2. Start emulator (Wait to start app)
3. and then removing it

Never had that problem again.

Comment: I found using a bluetooth microphone also removes the problem. But temporarily. Restarting the emulator without my bluetooth microphone connected produces the problem again. I did not try a corded microphone.

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but I was able to resolve this by editing the emulator and disabling the hw.audioInput setting.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to `C:\users\sahil\.android\avd` and delete `.lock` file.

Answer (score 0):

It's your new Windows 10 Update.

To Fix: Click Start, go to ⚙ Settings> Privacy Settings> Microphone. Turn On "Allow apps to access your microphone"

Answer (score 0):

In Window 10. I was able to fix it by doing...

1. go to C:\Users<YOUR_USER_NAME>.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_30_R_.avd
2. open config file
3. find hw.dPad and set yes like `hw.dPad = yes`
4. Restart your AVD