# Android Studio Emulator "Failed to create voice 'adc' "?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Whenever I open my AVD Manager in Android Studio, I get the messages in the event log :

```
Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_i`n

Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
```

Rest all the functions in the emulator are working fine till now. How to resolve this problem??

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49607825/75500) might help:

1. Go to: Tools > Android > AVD Manager
2. Press the "edit" (pencil) icon next to your AVD
3. Change "Graphics" to "Software"

Comment: That option is greyed out

Comment: That option is disabled here... is there any other way?