# Error launching the android project on emulator(API 28 on windows)

Tags: android-emulator

While trying to run the created Android project, I am getting below error and the project does not launch on the emulator even though the emulator gets launched successfully.

Error:

```
6:04 PM Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture

6:04 PM Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID

6:04 PM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

6:04 PM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

6:04 PM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

6:04 PM Emulator: %PATH%\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

6:04 PM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

6:04 PM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

6:04 PM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

6:04 PM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

6:04 PM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

6:04 PM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
```

Comment: You should plug in a microphone, run emulator for the first time, and it will solve. after that you can disconnect the microphone. Also

Answer (score 28):

It's your new Windows 10 Update. I couldn't figure it out for the life of me! I looked at 4 pages of results on Google and only saw the same old crap. So, here we go.

To Fix:
Click Start, go to ⚙ Settings> Privacy Settings> Microphone.
Turn On "Allow apps to access your microphone"

Also, MrPoopyB0tthole advised me of this fix as well.

Comment: @Gourav: I don't know what you're criticising about the answer of Mohsin, but his solution seems to be working and I found it very helpful to post it into this thread.
Mohsin: Many thanks and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok so i awarded him with 10 reputation! One upvote from me. One upvote to your comment also. Sorry for my behaviour

Comment: I'm giving an up-vote simply because the term "MrPoopyB0tthole" was mentioned in a serious conversation on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore since 1809 (may 2019). Android Studio isn't in the authorized application list... How to enable this ?

Comment: I have Windows 7 :( same issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same and fixed it by plugging in a mic and speaker.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve the problem if you try the mentioned steps in this thread: [Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010070/emulator-audio-failed-to-create-voice-adc)

Another trick I figured out by myself was to launch the emulator not via Debugging or Execution but from AVD Manager after starting Android Studio.

**UPDATE:**
Mohsins solution seems a better approach because it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the above solutions as well as the ones from this post [Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010070/emulator-audio-failed-to-create-voice-adc)

but it turned out none of them worked for me.

At the end of the day after downloading and installing new NVidia drivers, they magically started working again.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 i just plug in the microphone and the error is gone

Answer (score -1):

**Update:**
I think I finally solved it:

Go to ⚙ Settings> Privacy Settings> Microphone. Turn On "Allow apps to access your microphone" (if it's off, mine was on)
After this step, turn on "Voice recorder"

That solved the issue for me.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I have the same problem, tried the and the one from this post: [Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010070/emulator-audio-failed-to-create-voice-adc)

Old error log:

```
8:48 AM Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture

8:48 AM Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID

8:48 AM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

8:48 AM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

8:48 AM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

8:48 AM Emulator: C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

8:48 AM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

8:48 AM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

8:48 AM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

8:48 AM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

8:48 AM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

8:48 AM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

8:48 AM Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 43920 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

8:48 AM Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 43920 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

8:48 AM Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 43944 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

8:48 AM Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 43944 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

8:48 AM Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 48540 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

8:48 AM Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 48540 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)
```

Comment: You need to provide any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer