# App doesn’t run Android Studio emulator issue

Tags: android-emulator, amd-processor

When I start the Emulator in Android Studio it runs, but it doesn't open my application. [like this](https://f.top4top.net/p_118161zt20.jpeg) “ **there message down “ waiting for target device comes online** “

I use Ryzen 7 2700x, installed all SDK tools and use system image (recommended, Other images "ARM64-v8a,ARMEABI-v7a").

Another problem there is some error shown:

```
Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture
Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
Emulator: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
```

Comment: I guess this is related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651779/error-launching-the-android-project-on-emulatorapi-28-on-windows It's a windows 10 issue.

Comment: But isn’t for the main issue

Comment: Create a new emulator in another API level and check what happens?

Comment: @ashraf if you mean the image type I changed a lot

Comment: Then it seems an OS related problem to me. You could try a fresh installation of android studio, but before that delete all temporary files.

Comment: @ashraf I tried but without deleting temporary files, how can I do ?

Comment: Go to `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android` location and delete everything, open run menu and type `temp`, after opening this folder, delete everything, similar thing for `%temp%` folder.

Comment: @ashraf it’s working, thank you ❤️

Comment: That's great!  