# Android Studio Virtual Device - Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture

Tags: android

I can't get the emulator to work.

Tried disabling Recording and changing Graphics from Automatic to Software.
NOTE: I don't have a microphone.

21:12   Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture

21:12   Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID

21:12   Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

21:12   Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

21:12   Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

21:12   Emulator: C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

21:12   Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

21:12   Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

21:12   Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

21:12   Emulator: C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

21:12   Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

I want to use the emulator for development.

Comment: the logs seem to indicate that there is no sound driver installed. Did you disable it or does your development device not have one? Provide more details about your setup environment

Comment: It's Realtek Audio High Definition.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651779/error-launching-the-android-project-on-emulatorapi-28-on-windows

Comment: @PatrickBarboza Did you get this to work?  I'm having the same issue. I've tried/looked at diff solutions like acarlstein suggests. Nothing working when it had a week ago. Not sure if it was a Win10 update or what.

Comment: Same issue here, after updated win10 ......