# Android Studio emulator closes immediately after opening

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I start an emulator from Android studio, it closes immediately and it shows [these messages in the Android studio event log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBviD.png)

Previously, I had Genymotion installed, but the problem still occurs after I have successfully removed it (along with Virtual Box) from my computer.

I have VMware on my computer, but this was never a problem for successfully running an Android Emulator.

I have tried all of the proposed solutions on the internet (including reinstall of Android studio, update HAXM...), but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Check what 'adb devices' shows you.
Seems like you still have some parallel instance running

Comment: 'adb devices' shows an empty List of devices attached

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651779/error-launching-the-android-project-on-emulatorapi-28-on-windows ?

Comment: Yes I have tried this. The Microphone permission is enabled (still does not solve the problem). Anyway, as one of the comments on the post you've shared says: 'This doesn't seem to work anymore since 1809 (may 2019). Android Studio isn't in the authorized application list...'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is due to the fact that your pc doesn't have much memory or disk space to run android emulator.Please check this if it helps.

Comment: I have plenty of RAM (32 GB) and disk space (1.5 TB)

Answer (score 0):

May be it depends on your computer features.After you open a place where android studio is set up,everything might be okey