# I installed Android studio 3.4.2 latest available and when I tried to run basic application it shows these error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.4

```
org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.collectFailures(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:65)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:39)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:29)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:174)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:165)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at
```

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding project?

Comment: yes i tried, it doesn't work, also tried with file->invalidate cache and restart that also wont work.

Comment: In your **Terminal** section...type this ``gradlew assembleDebug --info```...you'll probably see the detailed error...from there we should know what to do.

Comment: This is what i got ==> 

7/18/2019

11:30 PM Gradle sync started

11:30 PM Project setup started

11:30 PM Gradle sync finished in 1 s 791 ms (from cached state)

11:31 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

11:31 PM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:93: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037


11:31 PM Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture


11:31 PM Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for .... few more like this.

Comment: So the issue appears when running an emulator?

Comment: yes, while running

Comment: Okay try plugging your microphone back into your computer..and create another virtual device in AVD manager..check this link for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651779/error-launching-the-android-project-on-emulatorapi-28-on-windows

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am done with fixes, here in answer section i putted the Solution which works for me.

Comment: Alright...great!!!

Answer (score 1):

Finally after lots of search, I got The answer which works for me now - 
**step 1 ==>** goto [ Build --> clean project ]
**step 2 ==>** Goto ["File -> Project Structure"] and **Change "Android Gradle plugin version " to 3.3.2**

**step 3 ==>** Restart Android Studio

Hope this will also works for you. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following

1. Build - Rebuild project

or

2.go to “File” -> “Invalidate Caches/Restart”

or

3. An invalid picture name may also cause the same (1.png....etc)

or

4. path length restriction. I think it's 256 characters maximum.

   Relocate your project and the build will succeed.

Hope these will help. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but
 1,2 didn't work, and

3. there is no picture, just now i installed and trying to run hello program. => that might not be the reason.

4. This is my file Location -> "C:\Users\Rahul\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication4" => Is it ok ?