# Android API 30 Emulator not working (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

So I was installing the Android API 30 Emulator on my PC using Android Studio, and when I tried to run it, I got a long list of errors.

```
4:30 AM Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

4:30 AM Emulator: handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf

4:30 AM Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed

4:30 AM Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed

4:30 AM Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture

4:30 AM Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID

4:30 AM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

4:30 AM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

4:30 AM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

4:30 AM Emulator: C:\Users\XTRAP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

4:30 AM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

4:30 AM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

4:30 AM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

4:30 AM Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

4:30 AM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have a limited internet every day so I don't want to delete my API. Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651779/error-launching-the-android-project-on-emulatorapi-28-on-windows) post could be relevant to your problem.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer, some microphone error are gone, but the Emulator still exits with code 0 without any keys being touched or anything being done.

Comment: did you solve this @XTRAP? same problem here

Comment: i was not able to solve this problem on my Windows pc, but on any other pc, this error never pops up. Although this seems like something related to internet and libraries... it is probably not able to download some libraries, and also some cpu bottleneck, even though i have enabled the CPU acceleration and virtualization from the BIOS. Try using the emulator on another device. 

maybe it is a problem specific to certain PCs with certain CPUs. I had an Intel Core i5 3470s when i tested this... try on a different CPU maybe it may work...