# avd opens home page but doesnt show my app in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, development-environment

to start off i am new to android development. I recently installed android studio, however, when I run my app the avd opens but doesn't display the app instead it shows the home screen with google play store phone and such.i  searched for the solution for days but no one really answered it.

Comment: Have you check if you have any build error or run time error while launching the launch-activity? Look for "Run" and "Logcat" tab in the bottom left corner of Android Studio. The shortcuts are usually Alt+4 and Alt+6

Comment: the error i receive is something like this

Comment: Error:

6:04 PM Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture

6:04 PM Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID

6:04 PM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

6:04 PM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

6:04 PM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc' .thanks in advance

Comment: I am not familiar with the error but can you try following steps in this SO answers?: [Error launching the android project on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651779/error-launching-the-android-project-on-emulatorapi-28-on-windows)

Comment: Thank you for your answer i did stumble upon that answer earlier but i don't have windows 10 or a mic on my pc

Comment: I see. Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010070/emulator-audio-failed-to-create-voice-adc) too? This answer seems to be more OS independent.

Comment: the issue seemed to have fixed itself i thank you for your time how can i upvote you