# How to start an Android emulator with large (8GB) ram and vm heap size?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm currently doing a research project on Android and for some reason, I need to run an Android emulator with API level 23, at least 8GB RAM and large VM heap size. However, I found that once the ram size exceeds 3.5GB, the emulator takes 100% of one CPU's core and hangs at the startup screen. I'm running it on a server with 512GB RAM so RAM won't be a problem. I've tried both the official Android emulator and Genymotion. Is it possible to accomplish the goal?

Comment: I think you might want to take a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063267/high-cpu-usage-with-android-emulator-qemu-system-i386-exe , I had high cpu usage before and disabling audio helped.