# Why is Android Emulator (qemu-system-i386) CPU usage so high (%360)?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I haven't used Android emulator for long time because of its performance. However, Android devs claimed that emulator is better now. Even better than a real device so I started using it. It works fine, but CPU usage is too high.

**Emulator Version: 25.1.7.0**

**Android SDK Tools: 25.1.7**

**Host Operating System: MacOS 10.10.3**

[image]

Comment: Some people reported that [disabling the sound](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33185427/334493) solved this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [High CPU usage with Android emulator (qemu-system-i386.exe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063267/high-cpu-usage-with-android-emulator-qemu-system-i386-exe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally CPU usage is OK, but it becomes very high after the laptop comes out of the sleep mode.  In this case I simply re-start the emulator.  It is very annoying.  Somebody suggested to edit AVD config.ini to set

```
hw.audioInput=no
hw.audioOutput=no
```

but it didn't help in my case.

#### Edit

The probelm seems to be fixed in Android emulator version 26.0.3.0 (build_id 3965150)

Comment: Same here... Wen starting emulator CPU usage is OK, but it becomes very high after the laptop comes out of the sleep mode..